# end tag for "body" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am getting the following errors when I try to validate my contact support page:

> end tag for "body" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
>
> ✉
>
> You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to
>   "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">".

Here is the source for my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylez.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Support Form</title>
<style type="text/css">
.textcontact {
font-size: small;
}
</style>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var name=prompt("Your name");
 var email=prompt("Your primary Email address");
 var phone=prompt("A phone number where you can be reached");
if (email== /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/){
document.write("Hello " +name, " Your Email address is " +email, " and your number is 
" +phone, " is that correct??");}else {alert("Please enter a valid Email 
address");document.write("Hello " +name, " Your Email address is invalid", " and your
number is " +phone, " in order for us to contact you, we need a VALID EMAIL ADDRESS,
please."); }
</script>
<body>
<h1>Contact Support</h1>
<table width="322" height="136" border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td>Leave your name</td>
<td align="center" valign="middle">Leave your primary Email address</td>
<td>Leave your phone number</td>
</tr>

</table>
<h2 class="textcontact"> We will contact you within 48 hours</h2>
<a href="index.html"><img src="images/300px-Basketball_pictogram.svg.png" width="88"
height="95" alt="home" /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

And for the life of me I cannot get this page to validate.

Also, I am getting this, which makes no sense at all:

> Line 21, Column 27: there is no attribute "height"
>
> ✉
>
> You have used the attribute named above in your document, but the
>   document type you are using does not support that attribute for this
>   element. This error is often caused by incorrect use of the "Strict"
>   document type with a document that uses frames (e.g. you must use the
>   "Transitional" document type to get the "target" attribute), or by
>   using vendor proprietary extensions such as "marginheight" (this is
>   usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead).
>
> This error may also result if the element itself is not supported in
>   the document type you are using, as an undefined element will have no
>   supported attributes; in this case, see the element-undefined error
>   message for further information.
>
> How to fix: check the spelling and case of the element and attribute,
>   (Remember XHTML is all lower-case) and/or check that they are both
>   allowed in the chosen document type, and/or use CSS instead of this
>   attribute. If you received this error when using the  element
>   to incorporate flash media in a Web page, see the FAQ item on valid
>   flash.

I created the entire page in Dreamweaver Cs5.5, and most of the code was auto-generated by it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You've got some answers, but in a general sense "auto-generated" code and "validation" don't always go together very well...

Comment: At least he's trying! :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a `<script>` elment outside the `<head>` and `<body>`. This is invalid. `<head>` and `<body>` are the ONLY allowed children of `<html>`.

Also, "height" is not a valid attribute on a `table` element.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because you put a script tag (`<script>`) between the end of the head tag (`</head>`) and the start of the body tag (`<body>`).

Answer (score 0):

Your script needs to be either in the head or body.

see [HTML Global Strucutre](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html)

Comment: Further to this, for the script in question I'd suggest putting it in the body, given that it uses `document.write()` to write (I assume) to the body...

Answer (score 0):

Script elements must be within a HEAD or BODY element. Yours is between the head and body so an opening BODY tag is placed before it. The validator then comes across another opening BODY tag, and you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is a space in the address for the doctype

```
    ww.w3.org /TR/xh
```

Also there is the script tags in-between the head and body tags

Lastly tables are seemingly not allowed to have height.